# Changing Bokeh table row count

Tags: bokeh

Below is a working example of a Bokeh table that is populated with selections from a scatter plot.

Once the table is first initialized, it always shows that many rows (too many or too few).

Is there a way to make the number of rows dynamic to fit the number of records selected?

Thank you

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.layouts import  row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc, show
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn


#Plotting points on chart.
initial_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(500, 2)), 
                          columns=["X","Y"], 
                          index=[str(i) for i in range(1,500+1)])

pointchart=figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=700, 
                  tools=['lasso_select','box_select'],
                  title="Points for selection")

pointchart_source= ColumnDataSource(initial_df )
pointchart_glyph= pointchart.circle("X","Y",source=pointchart_source,size=3.5)


#Source for table
source_df=initial_df 
source_df['ID']=source_df.index

#Making initial table source from dataframe. The table will always have this number of rows.
initial_source_for_table = ColumnDataSource(source_df)

columns =  [TableColumn(field='ID', title="Col1"),
           TableColumn(field="X", title="Col2"), 
           TableColumn(field="Y", title="Col3")]

global data_table #lets you access it in the callback.
data_table = DataTable(source=initial_source_for_table, columns=columns, width=800, height=400)


def on_selection_change(attr, old, new):
    newdataframe= pd.DataFrame(pointchart_source.data).loc[new]
    newdataframe['ID']=newdataframe.index
    newsource=ColumnDataSource(newdataframe[['ID',"X","Y"]].dropna(how='all'))


    data_table.source=newsource
    data_table.width=500
    data_table.height=500


pointchart_glyph.data_source.selected.on_change('indices',on_selection_change) 


#Show
layout=row(pointchart,data_table)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
!powershell -command {'bokeh serve --show Test_Table.ipynb'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Jupyter Notebook but this example should help you on your way.
Just count the number of selected points and alter the number of table rows with `table.height = number_points * 25`. Run the code with: `bokeh serve --show app.py`

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider, DataTable, TableColumn

max_i = 200
init_i = 6

def get_square(n):
    return dict(x = list(range(n)), y = [x ** 2 for x in range(n)])

source = ColumnDataSource(get_square(init_i))
columns = [
    TableColumn(field = "x", title = "x"),
    TableColumn(field = "y", title = "x**2"),
]

table = DataTable(source = source, columns = columns, width = 320)
slider = Slider(start = 1, end = max_i, value = init_i, step = 1, title = "i", width = 300)

def update_data(attrname, old, new):
    i = slider.value
    table.source.data = get_square(i)
    table.height = i * 25 + 25

slider.on_change('value', update_data)

layout = widgetbox(slider, table)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

BTW: you should not replace the entire ColumnDataSource in your callback but just assign a new data to it like in my example, that is use:

```
table.source.data = new_data
```

instead of:

```
table.source = new_source
```

Comment: Thank you! Question: Is assigning the new data instead of replacing the source much more efficient?

Comment: Yes. It is. Please check the [Bokeh documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html)